# Secure way to communicate with App Engine from Compute Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

There's a built-in way to setup [oauth](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/) on App Engine side, and it works great for request coming from my local machine with token generated by GoogleCredentials.[get_application_default](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)(), but it does not work for requests from Compute Engine with `NotAllowedError` exception on App Engine side.

I did multiple attempts to configure requests scopes to include `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.emails` as its required one, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out that when you create your instance with `Allow API access to all Google Cloud services in the same project.` it does **not** includes required User Info scope.

[image]

To include User Info scope, you have to uncheck `Allow API access to all Google Cloud services in the same project.`, go to `Access & Security` tab and explicitly enable User Info scope.

[image]

**UPDATE 2018-11-15**

The correct way to set email scope now is by using gcloud command:

```
gcloud compute instances set-service-account INSTANCE-ID --zone=us-central1-f --service-account=PROJECT-ID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,cloud-platform
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent detective work! Could you please also open a defect report on the public issue tracker about the misleading wording of the "allow API access" sentence? This will ensure the issue reaches the appropriate team (I think it's UI, could be docs) and the wording will be improved to avoid others facing the same problem you solved. Thanks again!

Comment: Done! https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=278&thanks=278&ts=1450593226